# Unable to reach breakpoint - C# / JQUERY

Tags: c#, jquery, debugging, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I'm attempting to set a breakpoint at  `$("#ButtonA").click(function () {` 
in the code shown below - however it is never hit when debugging and clicking on the button and I am unsure why.

P.S.

I am VERY new to C# and JQUERY - if I overlooked something simple I truly apologize.

### Index:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<asp:Label ID="lbltxt" runat="server">Click button when finished</asp:Label>
<button id="modal-opener">Click me</button>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Title">
    <p>Please enter your first name</p>
    <input id="Input" type="text" />
    <input id="ButtonA" type="button" value="Button A" />
    <input id="ButtonB" type="button" value="Button B" />
    <input id="ButtonC" type="button" value="Button C" />
</div>
```

### Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

     <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 200,
                width: 520,
            });

            $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
                $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
            });
            $("#ButtonA").click(function () {
                  $('#<%=lbltxt.ClientId%>').text('Hello World');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()


    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are using Visual Studio to do the JS breakpoint? Yeah, I don't think that is going to work. You would want to use a browser's developer tools to do a breakpoint in JS.

Comment: Visual Studio *might* be able to debug in-browser JavaScript.  (May require using IE, may require some settings in Visual Studio, not sure.)  But in general you'll find it's *a lot* easier to debug in-browser code with the browser's debugging tools.  Something like Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: @Turnerj - script breakpoints work in JS just fine... most people don't know how to use them, so indeed browser tools would be easier (as there is essentially exactly one option per browser... ignoring Safari).

Comment: @David, yep you are right apparently [it is possible via Internet Explorer only](http://youtu.be/SPmV5lLLSAA?t=1m4s).

Comment: Thanks!! I'll toy around with it a bit... I thought it had to do with a coding issue I am having :) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921050/c-sharp-jquery-unable-to-update-text-label-using-text-input-field